# How to unhide an extension in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions

I installed a Chrome extension, it had a small icon in the top bar between the URL and the three-dots menu.

Then, I hide the extension, thinking I would not need it anymore.
But now, I realize I want to always see this extension's icon, so I want to unhide it.

Most online solutions talk about small icons above "New tab", but I have no such icons, despite having dozens of installed extensions, most of them hidden:

[image]

Chrome 79.0.3945.130 on Mac 10.15.2

Comment: Reinstall the extension

Answer (score 9):

The method of hiding or showing extension icons in chrome has changed.  There is now an Extensions icon that looks like a puzzle piece to the left of the round User icon, and if you left-click on that it allows you to pin or unpin the extension icons from the toolbar.

Icon:

[image: Screenshot of the puzzle icon]

After right-click, you can pin/unpin extensions:

[image: show/hide extension icons in Chrome]

(screenshots taken with Chrome version 84.0.4147.89)

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is that as my screenshot shows, there was no puzzle piece icon.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: Chrome changed how this work.  Please see the fine answer from @JDGillis on how this works now (mid- and late-2020), not my answer below.  Of course, it may change again in the future!**

According to https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en:

> To show extensions you've hidden, click the right side of your address bar and drag it to the left. To bring hidden extensions back to your toolbar, click More More. Right-click the extension's icons, and select Show in toolbar.
> Some extensions don't have this option.

This is how it looks like when the cursor symbol changes.

[image]

This is NOT obvious but it works if you do it exactly: grab the right "edge" of the address bar (just to the right of the Add-Favorite star), and drag the edge to the left.  Any hidden extensions show back up!

I'm not sure what the other suggestion from Google is for (right-click on the icon), as I didn't need to do that to keep the icon back visible again after dragging the address bar to the left.

Comment: This doesn't work any more.

Comment: Yeah, same for me.  That's weird.  You can unpin one to hide it, but can't find a way to unhide yet...

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Chrome solved the problem.

It must have been in some weird ready-to-update state.