# extensions icon missing from a chrome window

Tags: google-chrome

extensions icon missing from a chrome window

Here you see the relevant part of two chrome windows.. (both are different google accounts).

One of them shows the extension icon, the other doesn't.

Any idea how to make it show(For the one that isn't showing it)?

[image]

Comment: [There is an option to hide the extension button.](https://superuser.com/questions/1523164/how-to-unhide-an-extension-in-chrome)

Comment: AT Ramhound I can't see it.

Comment: Try to run the setup of the latest version of Chrome, without uninstalling the current version.

Comment: @Ramhound you can hide individual extension icons (hide them to go into the Extensions toolbar icon) but not the whole Extensions icon (which is his question)

Comment: AT Ramhound. The way you wrote the text of that link is completely different to the actual question at that link!!  The thing you link to is not as you described. Your description says "There is an option to hide the extension button. ".  But that question you are linking to says "How to unhide an extension in Chrome?"  BTW if you just write a link then stackexchange might put the right description in there, the title of the q.

Answer (score -1):

You only see the ***Extensions*** button if you have installed in that Chrome profile extensions that have toolbar icons (not all extensions have toolbar icons.) In the profile you don't have the button you most likely have no Extensions installed/enabled, or just extensions that have no toolbar icons.

Go to Menu > Extensions > Manage Extensions (or `chrome://extensions/`) to see if you see there any extensions enabled.

Install an extension that does have a toolbar icon (any random one, for example **[Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb)**) and see if the button appears.

Comment: I think your answer isn't very clear.. I tried an edit which I think made clear what the solution was for me, which has a basis in what you wrote, but you removed it. I did accept your answer with the clarification at the end on what solved it. But you removing it I think your answer is very bloated(eg describing how to show extensions, recommending an extension. And your first sentence doesn't even apply to what my issue was), and with no clarification stating clearly what the solution was.

Comment: You write "The fact that an answer is correct can be seen by it being accepted, and perhaps details in the comment. It's not part of the answer." <-- actually to say a solution(eg what I had added), isn't part of the answer and should be a comment, is not true at all. I put the specific solution in the answer.

Comment: You're missing the point. You can certainly add/edit my answer to clarify it, or just add an answer yourself (if you think my answer didn't answer your question, which is ridiculous given the fact I wrote for you where to go and what to check there...) But adding a note with a specific thing of the answer helped you (a conversation within an answer) isn't an edit, it's a perfect comment

Comment: I explained you in my first paragraph why you don't see it (you do not have any extensions at all, or you have and they're not enabled, or you have extensions that don't have toolbars), then guided where to go to see what you have (where you will see if you have any extensions installed, if they are enabled), then I advised on how to test it (in case you have extensions but they aren't of the type that has a toolbar icon) to install an extension that I know has an icon

Comment: Part of the issue is your answer is not written well,You could have actually written the answer in one sentence. "For the extensions button to show, you must have at least one extension enabled, and that extension, has to have a toolbar button". That'd show the solution in one sentence, which could be the first one. But there's issues not just in the bloat of the answer, (which isn't the worst bit), but in a few other aspects to the style that'd take a while to explain why it's not well written and detracts from the quality.

Comment: Sure sure, that's why it helped you actually fix your issue... I know... 

Comment: no the reason why it helped wasn't because it was badly written, that's not what i'm saying.